# Set Filename of ToFile Block after Model has Finished

Tags: callback, simulink

I have a series of ToFile blocks in my Simulink model that each have a unique filename (e.g. "Pulse.mat".  I want to store the results of my simulation in timestamped folders based roughly on when I hit the run button / use the sim command.

My solution was to write two scripts, one called during the `InitFcn` callback and one for the `StopFcn`/`CloseFcn` callback (and `PreSaveFcn` callback).

The InitFcn callback would find all ToFile blocks and change the filename from "Pulse.mat" to something like "../runs//Pulse.mat", and the `StopFcn`/`CloseFcn`/`PreSaveFcn` to revert them to their original ".mat" names.  This worked on my small test model, however when I attempted to integrate it into my actual model I receive the following error:

```
Error evaluating 'StopFcn' callback of block_diagram '<model_name>'.

Caused by:
Cannot change parameter 'Filename' of '<ToFile Block>' while simulation is running. The block was made virtual as it was optimized for simulation
```

From my research I discovered that the `StopFcn` actually executes *before* the simulation is "done" (for whatever reason), but why did it work in my initial test model?  Do my ToFile blocks in my actual model have some property set that causes this error to occur?

Comment: You could make the StopFcn create a `timer` object that executes a short time after the StopFcn is executed, with the expectation that the model will have fully terminated by that time. The timer function would then do the name change.  (It may want to check that the model is still open and that the SimulationStatus property of the model confirms the simulation has terminated.)

Answer (score 2):

The block has been virtualised in your larger model; which seems to be changing the execution point.  One option might be to untick 'Block Reduction' in the 'Optimisation' pane of the model configuration parameters dialogue.

Alternatively, there might be another approach that you could try - 
Setting the model properties 'StartFcn' to something like :

```
evalin('base','resultTimTag = datestr(clock, ''yyyymmdd_HHhMM'');')
```

and setting the model properties 'StopFcn' to :

```
targetDir = evalin('base','resultTimTag');
mkdir(targetDir);
outputs = dir('*.mat');
for i=1:length(outputs)
    movefile(outputs(i).name,targetDir);
end
evalin('base','clear resultTimeTag');
```

It's possibly a little more brute-force than your approach, but seems to work quite nicely...